# Google Autocomplete - select first option on focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-places-api

I have the following code:

```
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "pl"}
};
var input: any = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
.....
});

$('#searchTextField').focusout(function (e) {
    $('.pac-container').find('.pac-item').first().click()
});
```

and the HTML:

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" id="searchTextField" placeholder="City"/>
```

However, now, when user clicks out of the input, without seleciton, the `place_changed` event is not fired. How can I fire this event on focusout?

Comment: How about: `$('.pac-container').find('.pac-item').first().attr('selected', true)`

Comment: @sideroxylon didn't worked.

Comment: OK.  I don't have the Google autocomplete set up at the moment, but maybe try this: `var item = $('.pac-container').find('.pac-item').first(); $('.pac-container').val(item).change();`